# AMQP MessageTooLargeError: AMQP Transport: Could not send

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

we are getting below error while sending 500KB data to IOT-HUB.

```
AMQP MessageTooLargeError: AMQP Transport: Could not send
```

We explored this and found the size limit in below documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ie/javascript/api/azure-iot-common/messagetoolargeerror?view=azure-node-latest&viewFallbackFrom=azure-iot-typescript-latest

we believe, this is kind of technical limitation, it is allowing up to 256KB.
Is there any workaround to send data larger than 256KB through `azure-iot-device-amqp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the message is over 256KB, [file upload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-file-upload) is an option.

You can refer to this [Device-to-cloud communications guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/sl-si/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-d2c-guidance). Batching is possible for up to 256KB messages. In order to enable the batching in the C or Python SDK, you need to use the SetOption API (IoTHubClient_SetOption in C) and set the "Batching" option to true or false. If you use Azure IoT SDK for c#, you can try to use **SendEventBatchAsync** method.

Comment: it sounds greate. O(∩_∩)O

Comment: Hi... My code is in Node.JS.. please specify something about Node.JS

Comment: I think you need to use File Upload. You can refer to the [device_blob_upload.js](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node/blob/master/device/samples/device_blob_upload.js) sample.@RamanGupta